# What OS can I use (other than Windows) to install Visual Studio, Microsoft SQL Server, ASP.NET and IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, operating-system

I currently have an Ubuntu 18.04 environment. For our course, we need to have Visual Studio, ASP.NET, Microsoft SQL Server and IIS installed. One solution was to install the Windows OS on VMware/VirtualBox, but since Windows OS on a virtual machine is a bit heavy on my laptop, is there any other slightly "light" OS that allows me to install the 4 requirements already mention?

Comment: IIS is Windows only. VS is only available on Windows and Mac. So in your case you can only use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As Lex Li says the IIS is Windows only,VS is only available on Windows and Mac. So you could only use the windows.

Here is a workaround, if you are familiar with the VS code, you could use VS code develop asp.net application, then you could use docker to run the asp.net application with IIS.

More details about how to use vs code in the linux, you could refer to below article:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

About how to use vs code to test application with docker, you could refer to below article:
https://medium.com/@agavatar/working-with-docker-in-visual-studio-code-756ea8b32abc